# чтение из бинарного файла в std::string

Tags: c++, файлы

Требуется прочитать файл в двоичном режиме с произвольного места и произвольной длинны.
Результаты записывать в `std::string`(каждый раз переписывая строку)
как лучше это сделать?

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    std::string target;
    uint32_t adr = 10;
    uint32_t len = 16;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("test.bin",  std::ios::binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 20)
    {
        file.seekg(adr+i, std::ios_base::beg);
        // соответственно первое что пришло на ум
        file.read(&target[0], len);
        std::cout << target.size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

пробовал так же крутится вокруг `std::istreambuf_iterator` , `copy_n`  и тому подобное но результата так и не добился.

Comment: `target.resize(len);` в самом начале сделайте.

Comment: *прочитать файл в двоичном режиме с произвольного места и произвольной длинны. результаты записывать в std::string* - что-то вызывает у меня это большие сомнения. Вот так, с нулевыми символами, записанный бинарный нуль, например - в строку? Не преобразуя в текст?

Comment: Сам read() это делает, но он работает с char*

Comment: Когда мне понадобилось сделать что-то подобное, ничего лучше не нашел (если выделить память для строки, конечно). Но `read` не возвращает количество считанных данных, нужно учитывать размер файла через 
 `iFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
  auto begin = iFile.tellg(); iFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
  auto end = iFile.tellg();`

Comment: докумекал до
    copy_n(istream_iterator<char>(file),len , back_inserter(target));
соответственно в конце цикла 
    target.clear().
   back_inserter явно костыль и я не понимаю, как от него избавится.